# unknown: this object doesn't support multiple channels,when using SecretSharing

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I am using Crypto++'s `SecretSharing` class . I want to pump shares (assume it is n shares) divided by `SecretSharing` to n string objects, then print the result. But my program always throws an exception. What can I do to avoid it?

```
    #include<iostream>//using cout、cin 
    #include<filters.h>
    #include<files.h>
    #include<osrng.h>
    #include<ida.h>
    #include<channels.h>
    #include<randpool.h>
    #include<string>
    #include<hex.h>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    int main()
    {

    try
    {
        AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
        string message = "I like Cryptopgraphy.";
        string Share1,Share2,Share3,Share4,tmp;
        StringSink S1(Share1);
        StringSink S2(Share2);
        StringSink S3(Share3);
        StringSink S4(Share4);
        ChannelSwitch* channelSwitch = new ChannelSwitch;
        channelSwitch->AddDefaultRoute(S1);
        channelSwitch->AddDefaultRoute(S2);
        channelSwitch->AddDefaultRoute(S3);
        channelSwitch->AddDefaultRoute(S4);
        StringSource Src(message,true,new SecretSharing(rng,2,4,channelSwitch));
        cout << "Share1:" << Share1 << endl;
        cout << "Share2:" << Share2 << endl;
        cout << "Share3:" << Share3 << endl;
        cout << "Share4:" << Share4 << endl;
    }
    catch(const Exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

The exception is:

```
unknown: this object doesn't support multiple channels*
```

---

I have another question about `ChannelSwitch` related to `SecretSharing`.
Crypto++'s manual says "ChannelSwitch can route input to different and/or multiple channels based on channel ID."

1. How can I set the channel's ID?
2. Can it route one input to many output channels?
3. Can it route many input to one output channels?

who can give me some examples about above questions.

Comment: Exception is :unknown: this object doesn't support multiple channels

Comment: this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917558/how-to-use-shamir-secret-sharing-class-in-crypto

Comment: Thanks for you! I found this code in crypto++'s test.cpp. But I want my code run correctly. Could you help me?

Comment: Ugh, the code you are working with kind of sucks. I think there is one better resource. That is the extended tests for Secret Sharing and Information Dispersal. You can find them at `TestSharing()` in [`validat0.cpp`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/validat0.cpp#L657). I think we probably need a wiki page on it, too. If you look closely, each share has the "Channel ID" prepended before the share by way of `strSinks[i]->Put((const byte *)channel.data(), CHID_LENGTH);`.

Comment: thanks for jww's answer.

Comment: Please, only one question per post. It is fine to create a question specific to `ChannelSwitch`. Asking for examples is explicitly off topic; if answers require sample code it is usually provided, so just leave it out. You can review my formatting changes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53478054/revisions) or by clicking "edited xxx time ago" above my name under the question. Markdown takes some getting used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these codes, but I don't understand some codes' meaning.
For example,the below codes.

---

```
        while (strSources[0]->Pump(256))
        {
            for (unsigned int i=1; i<threshold; i++)
                strSources[i]->Pump(256);
        }

        for (unsigned int i=0; i<threshold; i++)
            strSources[i]->PumpAll();
```

### why let every Source pump 256 bytes per time? why don't let them pump all data once?

```
  // Information Dispesal and Secret Sharing
    bool TestSharing()
    {
    std::cout << "\nInformation Dispersal and Secret Sharing...\n\n";
    static const unsigned int INFORMATION_SHARES = 128;
    static const unsigned int SECRET_SHARES = 64;
    static const unsigned int CHID_LENGTH = 4;
    bool pass=true, fail=false;

    // ********** Infrmation Dispersal **********//

    for (unsigned int shares=3; shares<INFORMATION_SHARES; ++shares)
    {
        std::string message;
        unsigned int len = GlobalRNG().GenerateWord32(4, 0xff);
        unsigned int threshold = GlobalRNG().GenerateWord32(2, shares-1);

        RandomNumberSource(GlobalRNG(), len, true, new StringSink(message));

        ChannelSwitch *channelSwitch = NULLPTR;
        StringSource source(message, false, new InformationDispersal(threshold, 
          shares, channelSwitch = new ChannelSwitch));

        std::vector<std::string> strShares(shares);
        vector_member_ptrs<StringSink> strSinks(shares);
        std::string channel;

        // ********** Create Shares
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<shares; i++)
        {
            strSinks[i].reset(new StringSink(strShares[i]));
            channel = WordToString<word32>(i);
            strSinks[i]->Put((const byte *)channel.data(), CHID_LENGTH);
            channelSwitch->AddRoute(channel, *strSinks[i], DEFAULT_CHANNEL);
        }
        source.PumpAll();

        // ********** Randomize shares

        GlobalRNG().Shuffle(strShares.begin(), strShares.end());

        // ********** Recover secret
        try
        {
            std::string recovered;
            InformationRecovery recovery(threshold, new StringSink(recovered));

            vector_member_ptrs<StringSource> strSources(threshold);
            channel.resize(CHID_LENGTH);

            for (unsigned int i=0; i<threshold; i++)
            {
                strSources[i].reset(new StringSource(strShares[i], false));
                strSources[i]->Pump(CHID_LENGTH);
                strSources[i]->Get((byte*)&channel[0], CHID_LENGTH);
                strSources[i]->Attach(new ChannelSwitch(recovery, channel));
            }

            while (strSources[0]->Pump(256))
            {
                for (unsigned int i=1; i<threshold; i++)
                    strSources[i]->Pump(256);
            }

            for (unsigned int i=0; i<threshold; i++)
                strSources[i]->PumpAll();

            fail = (message != recovered);
        }
        catch (const Exception&)
        {
            fail = true;
        }

        pass &= !fail;
    }

    std::cout << (fail ? "FAILED:" : "passed:") << "  " << INFORMATION_SHARES << " 
         information dispersals\n";

    // ********** Secret Sharing **********//

    for (unsigned int shares=3; shares<SECRET_SHARES; ++shares)
    {

        std::string message;
        unsigned int len = GlobalRNG().GenerateWord32(4, 0xff);
        unsigned int threshold = GlobalRNG().GenerateWord32(2, shares-1);

        RandomNumberSource(GlobalRNG(), len, true, new StringSink(message));

        ChannelSwitch *channelSwitch = NULLPTR;
        StringSource source(message, false, new SecretSharing(GlobalRNG(), 
           threshold, shares, channelSwitch = new ChannelSwitch));

        std::vector<std::string> strShares(shares);
        vector_member_ptrs<StringSink> strSinks(shares);
        std::string channel;

        // ********** Create Shares
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<shares; i++)
        {
            strSinks[i].reset(new StringSink(strShares[i]));
            channel = WordToString<word32>(i);
            strSinks[i]->Put((const byte *)channel.data(), CHID_LENGTH);
            channelSwitch->AddRoute(channel, *strSinks[i], DEFAULT_CHANNEL);
        }
        source.PumpAll();

        // ********** Randomize shares

        GlobalRNG().Shuffle(strShares.begin(), strShares.end());

        // ********** Recover secret
        try
        {
            std::string recovered;
            SecretRecovery recovery(threshold, new StringSink(recovered));

            vector_member_ptrs<StringSource> strSources(threshold);
            channel.resize(CHID_LENGTH);
            for (unsigned int i=0; i<threshold; i++)
            {
                strSources[i].reset(new StringSource(strShares[i], false));
                strSources[i]->Pump(CHID_LENGTH);
                strSources[i]->Get((byte*)&channel[0], CHID_LENGTH);
                strSources[i]->Attach(new ChannelSwitch(recovery, channel));
            }

            while (strSources[0]->Pump(256))
            {
                for (unsigned int i=1; i<threshold; i++)
                    strSources[i]->Pump(256);
            }

            for (unsigned int i=0; i<threshold; i++)
                strSources[i]->PumpAll();

            fail = (message != recovered);
        }
        catch (const Exception&)
        {
            fail = true;
        }

        pass &= !fail;
    }

    std::cout << (fail ? "FAILED:" : "passed:") << "  " << SECRET_SHARES << " 
       secret sharings\n";

    return pass;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, it is perfectly fine to answer your own questions like this. However, this is kind of an answer and new question rolled into one. Probably best to split off the question about the pump into a new question and link to it from the comments here.

Comment: Thanks  Maarten Bodewes . I am a starter. I will do that according to your recommendation next time.